# Generate Java android project with sencha

Tags: java, android, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

My question is:
It is possible to generate a java **android project structure** (with uncompiled classes .java) with **Sencha Cmd**?

I think Sencha Cmd must do that to generate an APK. It's the Android SDK that generate the APK.

I **need to modify the android project** before build it because Sencha is **limited in interaction** with the phone. (It's impossible to download a file form a generated APK by exemple... *I need to do that*)

If it's possible, **what command or manipulation** do I need to do?

Thank you for any help that can head me to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used Cordova to compile my application, it responded to my needs.
Cordova allows to download and execute files.